# Mount USB flash drive or external hard drive on Windows as drive letter A: or B:?

Tags: windows, windows-10, external-hard-drive, usb-flash-drive, drive-letter

Is there any way to get Windows to assign drive letter A: or B: (instead of D: or a subsequent letter) to a connected USB flash drive or external hard drive?

(This is purely for nostalgia purposes, because I miss the days when A: and B: were assigned to floppy drives!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't do that automatically when you just plug in a USB drive. (It will pick the first available letter after the regular hard drives in that case.)
But you can manually assign A or B via the Disk Management in Control-Panel or via  diskpart and Windows will remember that the next time you insert that same USB drive.

(PS: You can also assign A: or B: to a network-drive. Something most people don't know either.)

Comment: I couldn't find "Disk Administrator" in Control Panel or elsewhere on my machine, but the standalone program "Disk Management" did allow me to map my USB drive to A:!  If you think this is accurate and you'd like to edit your answer to reflect that and add instructions, I'll accept it! Otherwise, I'll add such an answer myself later.

Comment: _I couldn't find "Disk Administrator"_: run `diskmgmt.msc`.

Comment: @JonSchneider Microsoft has removed the Disk Managment entry from the menu in the latest W10 versions. It is still there but is now called “create partition” or something like that. You can also find it as a submenu in the “Manage Computer” control panel app.